# TSQL Sequential Number Generation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an application that, when a new user is added to a location, it is assigned a sequential number. So, for example, the first user at Location 01 would be assigned 01-0001, the second user 01-0002, etc.

While it is simple enough for me to find the max user number at any time for that location and +1, my issue is that I need this to be thread/collision safe.

While its not super common, I don't want one query to find the max() number while another query is in the process of adding that number at that same moment. (it has happened before in my original app, though only twice in 5 years.)

What would be the best way to go about this? I would prefer not to rely on a unique constraint as that would just throw an error and force the process to try it all again.

Comment: Why wouldn't the ROW_NUMBER function work for you?

Comment: Because that is global to the table and not sequential within the assigned location id.

Comment: What is the purpose of the sequential number? Why not just have a global identity then you can calculate the sequence within a specific location if needed. What is the sequential number actually used for?

Comment: Could always use durable keys too, or NEWSEQUENTIALID, the latter prone to crashes

Comment: @MartinSmith That is the user's ID within the system. I don't just use a global identity because I have to remain consistent both with my previous incarnation of the program, and the incarnations that preceeded me. (This is a long existing process)  The user numbering can't exceed 4 digits and eventually an identity field would (and also its a bit less friendly to non-techie people using the system.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT @UserId = MAX(UserId)
FROM YourTable WITH(UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK, ROWLOCK)
WHERE LocationId = @LocationId

--TODO: Increment it or initialise it if no users yet.

INSERT INTO YourTable (UserId, Name)
VALUES (@UserId, @Name)

COMMIT
```

Only one session at a time can hold an update lock on a resource so if two concurrent sessions try to insert a row for the same location one of them will be blocked until the other one commits. The `HOLDLOCK` is to give serializable semantics and block the range containing the max.

This is a potential bottleneck but this is by design because of the requirement that the numbers be sequential. Better performing alternatives such as `IDENTITY` do not guarantee this. In reality though it sounds as though your application is fairly low usage so this may not be a big problem.

Another possible issue is that the ID will be recycled if the user that is the current max for a location gets deleted but this will be the same for your existing application by the sounds of it so I assume this is either not a problem or just doesn't happen.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks, I will give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `sequence` object described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx).
Create a new sequence is very simple, for example you can use this code

```
create sequence dbo.UserId as int
start with 1  
increment by 1;
```

With `sequence` object you don't need to be aware about any collision. Sequence will return always next value in every time you get it with `NEXT VALUE FOR` statement, like in this code

```
select next value for dbo.UserId;
```

The next value will be return correctly even if your rollback transaction or even if you get next value in separate, paralel transactions.

Comment: They would need a different sequence for every location. It doesn't guarantee sequential either in the event of rolled back transactions or loss of cache during service restart for example.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, you are right - they would need another sequence for every location. If you mean the lack in sequence beceause rollback, then you are right also - but there is no possibility to return the same value twice wihout restarting the sequence object. About loss of cache you are right - anythig that was not save in file will be lose after restart but as far as I aware this could be happen only if you create sequence with CACHE option.